# Impedir alteração do objeto no relaciomento

Tags: django

Boa tarde, estou tentando evitar alteraçao de um objeto quando
fizer parte de um relacionamento, na minha view.py customizada deu certo,
mas no arquivo admin.py ocorre um erro..ha como me ajudar?

funcao na view.py

```
def altBloco(request, id):
    """
     verifica se o usuario tem perimissao, para fazer a operacao
    """
    if not request.user.has_perm('alocar.change_bloco'):
        return render(request, 'alocar/permissao1.html')

    bloco = get_object_or_404(Bloco, pk=id)
    form = AddBlocoForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=bloco)
    values = Sala.objects.select_related('bloco').filter(bloco__id=id)
    if form.is_valid():
        if values:
            messages.info(request, 'NÃO pode ser editado, já faz parte de algum relacionamento')
        else:
            form.save()
        return redirect('alocar:addbloco')

    return render(request, 'bloco/altbloco.html', {'form': form})
```

funcao no admin.py

```
@admin.register(Bloco)
class BlocoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('bloco',)
    search_fields = ('bloco',)
    ordering = ('bloco',)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super(BlocoAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        values = Sala.objects.select_related('bloco').filter(bloco__id=id)
        if form.is_valid():
            if values:
            messages.info(request, 'NÃO pode ser editado, já faz parte de algum relacionamento')
        else:
            form.save()
```

[image: alterar bloco]

Comment: Viva, não percebi bem no outro post onde estava o detalhe da tua questão. Queres evitar que seja editado um atributo? No models podes definir editable=False. Valida se é isso que precisas.

Comment: @ErnestoCasanova.. boa noite...nao apenas o atributo, mas o objeto inteiro..se ja fizer parte de um relacionamento...nao pode ser editado...so poderá ser editado se nao fizer parte de nenhum relacionamento... por exemplo "BLOCO A" tem um relacionamento com "SALA A100" entao o mesmo nao pode ser editado, para ser editado tem que estar livre de relacionamento

Comment: Ok, agora percebi. Realmente no models seria o local onde definirias isso e ficara disponível em todo o lado, até no admin, essa tag que indiquei só irá fazer ao atributo e como fk e não ao models. Nsse caso de uso, estás a atualizar uma flag no teu models com signals? Partilha o models para eu pensar numa solução, penso que terá de ser num manager no models.

Answer (score 0):

Viva, estive a analisar e uma solução simples com o admin, seria adicionares uma flag ao teu models e quando for utilizado este models passas esta flag a true, e no admin com uma função adicional passas todos os atributos a modo leitura, não permitindo editar como querias.

**models.py**

```
class Bloco(models.Model):
    ...
    already_taken   = models.BooleanField('Atribuido', default=False)
```

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Bloco)
class BlocoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('bloco',)
    search_fields = ('bloco',)
    ordering = ('bloco',)
    exclude=('already_taken',) # excluis a flag para controlo de atribuicao

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj and obj.already_taken:
            return ['all_your_fields'] # não incluis already_taken, para não aparecer na form admin.
        else:
            return []
```